# WSO2 API Manager Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi I am looking to deploy the WSO2 API Manager store publicly but would like to change the theme (not simply to use a pre-existing theme) but to revamp and add my own branding etc. I've searched online for tutorials but the examples show how to orchestrate services and not how to rebrand the pages...any docs too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this guide to add your own [theme.](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2012/09/customizing-api-store-publisher-part1)

Comment: Though it's not detailed, it provides an overview of Jaggery structure for one to get up to speed quickly. Thanks :)

Comment: Refer these documentation[1,2].             
[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+the+API+Store
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme